# Extracting ship locations from KML file using Python?

Tags: python, kml

I was wondering whether it was possible to extract ship data such as the longitude and latitude of each ship from a KML file provided by http://aprs.fi/, relative to one's location, into a CSV file using a Python script?

**KML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<NetworkLink>
    <name>APRS: All targets in view</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <Snippet maxLines="2">43Â°13.00&apos;Â N 27Â°55.00&apos;Â E - Real-time APRS network tracking of all APRS targets in the world</Snippet>
    <description><![CDATA[<p>Initial view: 43Â°13.00'Â N 27Â°55.00'Â E</p>
        <p>Google Earth application by <a href='http://aprs.fi/'>aprs.fi</a></p>]]>                                        </description>
<LookAt>
    <longitude>-0.3226803743656781</longitude>
    <latitude>53.60036183734124</latitude>
    <altitude>0</altitude>
    <heading>-11.4292926524615</heading>
    <tilt>1.734758838337611</tilt>
    <range>67610.58111833796</range>
    <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
</LookAt>
<Link>
    <href>http://aprs.fi/aprsupdate.kml?units=metric&amp;units_temp=C&amp;</href>
    <refreshMode>onExpire</refreshMode>
    <viewRefreshMode>onStop</viewRefreshMode>
    <viewRefreshTime>1</viewRefreshTime>
</Link>
</NetworkLink>
</kml>
```

The KML file provided by the above website integrates into Google Earth and shows a live feed of each ship's location around the world.

**What I ultimately want to do is everytime the Python script is run, it would extract the co-ordinates of each ship at a specific location from this KML file, into a CSV file.**

**The Python script would run every 60 seconds and therefore update the co-ordinates in the CSV file.**

**If anyone could point me in the right direction then I would be eternally grateful. Thanks!**

Comment: you could try using scrapy selector to select the field you want http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`KML` is `XML` file so you can use modules `lxml`, `BeautifulSoup` or `xml.dom.minidom` and `csv` to save it. To read files from server you can use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) or `pyCurl`.

Scraping data from server is very popular so there is also [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html) framework.

If you use Linux you can use `cron` / `cronjob` to run script every 60 seconds`

Comment: Thanks @furas! The problem I'm struggling to overcome is how to actually extract the data from the KML that is located on the APRS server. Their KML file is updated regularly on a server, and then the above KML file is downloadable and linked to the server version.

Comment: Do you have links to KML files ? Are the links always the same ? (the same name)

Comment: BTW: I see there is [API](http://aprs.fi/page/api) and probably you can get all as JSON.

Comment: The link to the KML file is http://aprs.fi/aprsupdate.kml?units=metric&amp;units_temp=C&amp;

Ah yes, I've seen the API. I'll have a look at it and get back to you. Thanks for your help so far! :)